# Linq query syntax equivalent group by id having sum(amount) > x amount

Tags: linq

I have a datatable in my example like this (the real one has a few more columns than below):

```
Id             Amount
1              2
12             4
12             6
22             7
22             7
```

I need to group by Id having Sum(Amount) > 5 like this:

```
Id             Amount
12             10
22             14
```

I first GroupBy, then project the groups to DataRows, then create the DataTable using CopyToDataTable extension. And it works perfectly.

I am new to this Linq method and query syntax, can you please advise me where I can add the clause HAVING SUM(Amount) > 5 in addition to the existing query below?

Below is my query:

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                  var row = dt.NewRow();

                  row["Id"] = g.Key;
                  row["Amount"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Amount"));

                  return row;
              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of achieving this:

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
    .Select(r =>
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = r.Key;
        row["Amount"] = r.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount"));
        return row;
    })
    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Amount") > 5)
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

or

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
    .Where(r => r.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount")) > 5)
    .Select(r =>
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Id"] = r.Key;
        row["Amount"] = r.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("Amount"));
        return row;
    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Dear Carlo Bos, Thanks for giving solution to my problem. Would you be able to explain a bit about your query order. I see you have put another Select statement method? Just an extra question, if i want to OrderBy Id, where the the OrderBy method should be placed?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use data table rows all the way, eliminating the use of the object enumerable and the need for two `Select` statements. I've also added the `OrderBy` to show where that would go.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Carlo. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello Carlos, sorry to disturb you again on the same issue. I am curious about your query, can the Where method be placed between GroupBy and Select? What is the impact by doing so? Hope you don't mind answering this

Comment: Yes, absolutely, However it will will be a toss up between creating rows that will be filtered out or doing the aggregate sum calculation twice. The answer above is simpler to read understand.

Comment: Carlo, much appreciated for your additional comment. Have a great day!